Struggling with question about non-increasing energy function in a symmetric weight neural network
I'm trying to work out problem 1.1 on page 13 in Statistical Mechanics of Learning
where the authors ask you to prove the following claim. Consider a neural network model with neurons whose activations are either 1 or -1 at each timepoint and with symmetric weights ($J_{ij} = J_{ji}$), and which evolves according to the following threshold dynamics:
$$
S_i(t+1) = \text{sgn} (\Sigma_j J_{ij}S_j(t) - \theta_i)
$$
where sgn$(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and sgn$(x) = -1$ otherwise.
Prove that the energy $H(\mathbf{S}) = -\Sigma_{i,j} J_{ij} S_i S_j$ can never increase (i.e. must decrease or stay the same over time).
I don't know how to prove this (although I've tried). Actually, I think it's false because I have this putative counterexample. Let's imagine a very basic "network" consisting of only two neurons, labeled 1 and 2. The symmetric weight $J_{12} = 1$. At initial time $t= 1$, both neurons are "on", so the energy value is -2. Suppose the neurons have different thresholds, such that $\theta_1 = -1, \theta_2 = 1$. Then according to the threshold dynamics defined above, $S_1(2) = 1$ but $S_2(2) = -1$ (basically the first neuron is activated at time step 2 because its threshold is lower, while the second neuron is not activated because it has a higher threshold). As a result, the energy value at time step 2 will be 2. So the energy did increase from -2 to 2. But I feel like I am probably missing something here.

You forgot the bias term in the energy. Check out this similar question: Can energy increase during neuron dynamics?
